# how to use vodafone adsl router as normal router

Tags: adsl, dsl, adsl-router, dsl-modem, adsl2+

I got a vodafone dsl easybox 602 router and modem from a friend of mine. At my home I have broadband connection. I want to use this broadband connection with the vodafone router and use it as wifi router. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't own a vodafone easybox 602, but from [This page](http://www.ebay.it/itm/Vodafone-DSL-EasyBox-602-DSL-WLAN-Router-Analogico-Endgeraet-UMTS-Router-/251683216410?hash=item3a997d1c1a) I see that its engineering is identical to all the wifi routers I worked on.

You must do this way:

- identify the subnet of your house, where you share the internet from the dsl router, say it's 192.168.0.*
- enter the router, as explained in [this page](http://services.sony.hu/support/data/blu-ray-connect/BRD/BDVEX70/EN/3135/3/Step_1.html), and set the router LAN to 192.168.0.*
- configure wifi network on 602 according to your needs; you may use for the wifi network the same subnet as lan, 192.168.0.*; I think the router can be configured as bridge, separating ip ranges on wifi from those in lan; or you can use for wifi another subnet
- connect one of the 4 lan port to dls router

You should be done!